# Laravel's exceptions

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5.5

I would like to know what's the most professional way to handle exceptions with Laravel.

Lets say that I have table with posts. Lets assume that one user has deleted the post and the second one did the same after 2 seconds. Then we are throwing an exception - by example PostNotFoundException. Then I would like to redirect user to view with posts with custom error. Is it a good way of doing it?

**Exception catching:**

```
try {
    \App\Post::destroy(1);
}   catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new UserNotFoundException($e->getMessage());
}
```

**PostNotFoundException**:

```
class PostNotFoundException extends \Exception {

  public function render () {

    return redirect()->route('posts.index')->with([
        'error' => 'User not found.'
    ]);    

  }

}
```

What is the best way of doing it? Can you provide me any example?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to be catching the exceptions because it can become quite costly. You could just do a simple if statement in the delete method to check status of the post? If you are using softDeletes then you would just check the value of that, if not you would just see if it exists.